# OCaml: unexpected exception with Unix.getlogin when stdin redirected

Tags: unix, ocaml

I found out the next issue in this simple code:

```
let () =
    print_endline "Hello";
    print_endline (Unix.getlogin ())
```

Running in the normal case, with `./a.out` gives:

```
Hello
ricardo
```

But running like `./a.out </dev/null` makes Unix.getlogin fail:

```
Hello
Fatal error: exception Unix.Unix_error(20, "getlogin", "")
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I just tried this on my system: Mac OS X 10.6.8/OCaml 3.12.0 and I don't see the problem.  The output is the same in both cases.  What is your system?

Comment: Linux, I have read again man 3 getlogin and I saw the "bug" in glibc about redirecting the stdin :-/

Comment: Yes, bkconrad nailed it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirecting the input of a program overrides its controlling terminal. Without a controlling terminal, there is no login to be found:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/2
$ tty < /dev/null
not a tty
```

You can, however, still find a user's name (perhaps) by getting the user's id (`getuid`) and looking up his [passwd entry (related docs)](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#TYPEpasswd_entry) (`getpwuid`), then finding his username in it.

Comment: The answer should come from the uid of the process, not from the controlling terminal.  But still this could be the problem.

Comment: Assuming it calls the real `getlogin` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/getlogin), then it does, in fact, come from the controlling terminal.

Comment: Wow.  On BSD (and Mac OS X), it's a separate value set when you log in.  It is not based on getuid() or geteuid() as I expected, but not on controlling terminal either.  Seems a little better to me.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your application:

- if you don't really care about the value returned by "getlogin", you can do something like:

  ```
  try
    Unix.getlogin ()
  with _ -> Sys.getenv "USER"
  ```

  you will probably get something better than `getuid`, since it will also work for programs with Set-User-ID flags (sudo/su).
- if you really care about the value returned by "getlogin", i.e. you really want to know who is logged in, you should just fail when getlogin fails. Any other solution will give you only an approximation of the correct result.